# Why can't I ask a question after 6 months of being blocked?

Tags: support, post-ban, banning

I have been blocked because I have deleted too many questions in a cleaning up attempt.

Apparently, one gets another chance after 6 months.

However, as far as I know more than 6 months have passed, but I still cannot ask new questions.

Comment: Your last (non-deleted) question was posted in April, that's not 6 months ago (in fact you asked 4 questions in April and 1 in the latter half of March)

Comment: wow did you just remove my oppinion on how some people don't like the harsh behaviour in here? so we can not talk about this? @yivi

Comment: I removed it because it's not relevant to your question. This kind of "ranty" statements are usually not well received, and won't help your question to be well received. You want to ask for help to get over your ban, or complain about the site?

Comment: @yivi thanks for the information. I'm a bit confused. So my latest post is older then 6 months but I wrote something (whilst being banned) that is younger? Well I thought I could mention it. Should I realy open a post about how harsh it is in here? I already get 3 negativ for not knowing why I'm banned right now.

Comment: Negative votes here aren't the same as on main. Downvotes here usually represent a disagreement with a statement or an opinion. The statement being disagreed with here is "However, as far as I know more than 6 months have passed".

Comment: Users will vote very freely on meta, but it wont affect your reputation or your account. In this case, some users may be downvoting because you state "it's been more than 6 months since my last question", when it's apparent that it's not. I haven't voted in anyway myself. But there, have an upvote.

Comment: Since six months haven't passed, your only option is either wait until six months _really_ pass, or wait until a mod like George (a user with ♦ besides their username) provides you with a list of deleted questions for you to edit and improve. You can also try improving non-deleted questions, but I imagine your deleted questions have worse scores than the ones you haven't deleted.

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon It may just be your memory failing you, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55706351/why-does-python-3-7-show-a-syntax-error-when-using-function-parameter-types) is your latest question, you can see it was asked in April

Comment: @NickA well yes thats about right. But that question is related to a course I took in February xD I don't get it.

Comment: @yivi ou I tried this before. They can't be rescued. Complete nonsense. I tried to ask something similar, however this is not allowed and I got even more punishment.

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon Users are only supposed to downvote questions on meta according to the hover reason but unfortunately they do not (Feature Requests excepted).

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon As long as the algorhitm considers you question banned, you are allowed one question every six months. So if your last question was in april, the next question you'll be able to ask will be in october. This pattern continues until your old questions get undeleted/upvoted enough to break the ban, or you ask enough high quality new questions (undeleted and with upvotes) to break the ban. So your quickest and best bet is to improve existing questions

Comment: Despite what others users are telling you, there is no evidence the votes are **not** following the tooltip guidance. The question could be said to be poorly researched because of the evidently false claim of six months having passed. The only evidence of voting against that guidance is my own upvote. The other upvote I can't tell who cast it nor why. They could have thought your question was useful, for example. Further antagonizing users of meta with false claims about voting patterns serves no purpose.

Comment: Er. [You complained about this *very* thing in April](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383003/does-one-get-notified-if-a-post-does-not-get-migrated).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The hover reason merely states that a question doesn't show research effort, is unclear, or is not useful. There's a lot of latitude in deciding exactly what things make a post "not useful." For example, I think that the fact that the premise of this question is evidently untrue certainly makes it "not useful."

Answer (score 6):

From oldest to newest questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931761/how-do-i-correctly-install-egypt-on-a-mac

  This question wasn't a bad question (it was mis-tagged c++, but that's minor); one thing that you could do is to edit the question a little to clean it up (removing "do you have any recommendations" and changing it to "how do I run egypt after installation on Mac OS X?" which is restating your original problem.  I would then look at the comment that explained how to run it, and if that solves your problem, post a solution that says how you got it to work.  Your question isn't just for you, it's for everyone that may have this problem, so expanding it and answering it is just fine.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266981/multiple-imus-relative-pose-estimation

  For this question it appears you're asking for pre-emptive guidance.  Stack Overflow isn't the best place to ask for pre-emptive guidance. It is the best place to ask for help once you have a demonstrable problem, but we can't tell you hypothetically what will work or won't work. We just don't have the necessary context.  I recommend that you try what you asked us about in this question and then if you have issues, edit the question into the actual issues you encountered.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775064/interpreting-can-bus-bytes

  I'm not sure we can ever help you with this question, at least not on Stack Overflow.  We'd need to reproduce it, and we'd need to know crucial information that only you can tell us (whether it's little or big endian).
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564777/rotating-gyro-data

  I also don't know if we can help you with this question.  I don't understand enough of what you're asking of us to propose any advice.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458024/accessing-deepl-with-python3

  We need to see your code; since this question is about a problem with your code. I recommend distilling the question down to the facts: You're trying to access *X* API with *Y* Code, and you're getting *Z* error. How to resolve *Z* error?
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101281/waking-up-a-computer-without-wake-on-lan-wol

  This question (in some form) could be useful on Serverfault or SuperUser or another site; but I don't see it as a Programming question.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121047/creating-a-wrapper-for-a-game-to-extract-in-game-information

  This is an interesting question though it's a bit broad and unclear. Do you want to create a wrapper for all games? For a specific game? What do you need to capture? Why? What will you try to use it to do?  I don't see how this question can be edited into shape; but you're welcome to try.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55335288/whats-the-reason-devices-can-sometimes-not-be-pinged-by-their-names

  This is a networking question or a serverfault question (hint: Sometimes SysAdmins turn off ICMP, which is what Ping uses), but not a programming question.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55524241/solving-a-differential-equation-in-a-web-application

  This is a very broad question.  This is another of those 'try to implement something and come to us with a specific problem'. We're not good at pre-emptive advice.

I hope this helps, when you have edited questions, feel free to flag them for moderator attention and I'll undelete them as appropriate (or you can undelete them, in some cases).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199089/discussion-on-answer-by-george-stocker-why-cant-i-ask-a-question-after-6-months).